# Networkx min_weighted_vertex_cover in python returns whole set instead of vertex cover

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, networkx, vertex-cover

I have an adjacency matrix `A` with `nodes = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

```
A = [[0,1,1,0,0,0],[1,0,1,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0]]
```

I want to find the minimum weight vertex cover of this graph. I converted this adjacency matrix with

```
g_n = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A)
```

and following function to find the vectex cover

```
cover = nx.min_weighted_vertex_cover(g_n)
```

But the output is

```
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

which is just the set of all vertices. The expected output should be

```
set([1, 2, 3])
```

What is wrong with this process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function is approximate and returns "*a set of vertices whose weight sum is no more than 2 * OPT*" ([Prooflink](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.approximation.vertex_cover.min_weighted_vertex_cover.html)). In your case, OPT=3, so the set of all six nodes is an acceptable answer.